# Splitting an integer up in original order and storing it in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, split, integer

How can this be done? Say the user enters an integer 14865, how can I then cut up that integer and put it into an array in the exact same order like so:[1, 4, 8, 6, 5]. I've tried using the %10 method, but it returns it back to front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to turn the integer into a string and then use the string `.split()` method to create an array containing each digit. At that point each element of the array will be a string, so loop over the array to turn each array element from a string to a number (or just use `.map()`):

```
var x = 14865,
    a = x.toString().split("").map(function(v) { return +v; });

// a is now [1, 4, 8, 6, 5]
```

Note that if the integer is entered by a user you can skip the `.toString()` part, because it will already be a string unless you've explicitly converted it to a number.

P.S. You mentioned "the %10 method" returns the values "back to front" - you don't show how you implemented that method, but if your current code extracts the digits one at a time and adds them to the end of the array "back to front" why not avoid that problem by inserting the digits at the *beginning* of the array with the [`.unshift()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)?

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!! But .map(function(v) { return +v; }); wasn't needed though because I only need it in an array for checking of length, but I will keep this for future reference.

Comment: What do you mean "checking of length"? Length of what? (Note also that thg435's answer uses the same idea as mine, but does it more neatly by using `.map(Number)`.)

Comment: length of the array, but need to keep the order for checking the first index in the array as well. I already know how to do this (meaning the length and index part).

Comment: Basically I've never even heard of the .unshift() method and I deleted the failed attempt at the %10 method and am too sleepy to remember what I typed out

Comment: If you're saying that you want to test how many digits are in the number and what the first digit is you don't need an array at all. If the user entered the number (i.e., you extracted it from an input element) it will already be a string, so just use `num.length` for the length and `num.charAt(0)` for the first digit.

Answer (score 1):

After you've made the array by getting each digit, like you said you already did, just reverse the array

```
var digitArray //your calculated array
digitArray = digitArray.reverse()
```